# Excel Formula to highlight range based on date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to create a formula to call out an entire range where there is a date less or equal to today's date.

In this example, I have a number 600259 (Column A) where there are dates that are less than today's date. I would like my formula to mark ALL as true instead of just the rows where the dates are less than.

[image]

My current formula is:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A60,I:I,I60)
```

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A60,I:I,"<=12/7/2023")
```

I know I'm close but I think I need a second set of eyes to help

Comment: Then don't test the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question but if you want to mark all dates in the past (less than today) try doing this instead

```
=IF(A1 >= TODAY(),TRUE)
```

where A1 is the date you want to check

you can then count the ones that are true with:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,TRUE)
```

A being your date column

if you want to you can combine them both into:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,">="&TODAY())
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: after you explanation I believe this is what you're looking for:

[image]

Using the formulas from above you'll need to add a few new columns either in this sheet or an auxiliary one.

An ID column, a COUNT column and a IF column but you can merge this last pair

For the count column you'll need:

```
=COUNTIFS(I:I,">="&TODAY(),H:H,K3)
```

where I is the date column and H is the ID column

for the if you'll just need:

```
=IF(L3>0,TRUE)
```

where L3 is the count right beside it

you can merge this two into:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(I:I,">="&TODAY(),H:H,K3)>0,TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific. the Date column is column I. ID numbers which each have a range of dates. If any of those dates within that same ID number are less than today's date I want them all to say TRUE. Otherwise all to say False. Hopefully that helps but your answer does give me some ideas.

Comment: @Deke fair enough, I just don't understand exactly how the IDs work with the date, do you want to make a function that checks if any of the dates within a single ID are in the past to label that ID as "TRUE"?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for thanks for your help! I think I was stuck on the countifs too much